# Why are there so many primes in the convergents of Pi?

Tags: prime-numbers, pi

Recently, I was looking into fractional approximations of pi, such as $\frac{22}{7}$ or $\frac{355}{113}$. I found that there was a name for these approximations, 'convergents' of pi, and I found a list of the first 100. Upon inspection of list, it seemed that **a lot** of the fractions had odd numerators or denominators. Furthermore, it seemed a lot of the fractions had **prime** numerators or denominators!

A quick check with mathematica confirmed this:
**91 out of the first 100 convergents had prime numerators or denominators!** Even more astounding, **6 out of the 9 that didn't hold this property occured within the first 11 convergents.**

This seems like it can't simply be a coincidence, but I couldn't find anything about it online. Why is this true?

Comment: Without thinking about it very hard, it occurs to me that if you reduce a fraction to lowest terms, so that the numerator and denominator are relatively prime, the odds that at least *one* of them is itself prime go up significantly, surely.

Comment: And obviously, all of them have to have at least an odd numerator *or* and odd denominator (or both).

Comment: @BrianTung I also thought along those lines, but I feel that argument would only work if I was saying odd, not prime. Then again, when a number is odd it also has a better change of being prime, but this seems to be on too large a scale (91%) to just be a question of fully simplified fractions.

Comment: Are you able to produce convergents on your own?  If so, it might be interesting to try it for some (quasi-)randomly chosen number, and see if the same proportion holds, or if the difference is significant.

Comment: ...and of course, the convergents thus produced will always be in lowest terms.

Comment: @brian-tung: your point stands well if you say almost the same but taking Jim's answer in account. The concentration of primes drop with the numbers growing and thus having a convergent with both numerator and denominator prime is vanishing.

Comment: @PinhollowEuri: Aha!  I had thought about that, but didn't really think through how that would affect the proportion.

Answer (score 34):

Your data seems to be exactly backwards.  Of the first 100 convergents of pi, only 9 of them have either a prime numerator or a prime denominator, with 91 of them having both composite numerator and composite denominator.  Moreover, 6 of the 9 that have a prime numerator or denominator are in the first 11 convergents.

Here's the Mathematica code that I used:

```
In[1]:=   c = Convergents[Pi, 100];

In[2]:=   test = PrimeQ[Numerator[#]] || PrimeQ[Denominator[#]] &;

In[3]:=   Length[Select[c, test]]
Out[3]:=  9
```

According to Mathematica, these 9 are
$$
3,\;\; \frac{22}{7},\;\; \frac{355}{113},\;\; \frac{103993}{33102},\;\; \frac{833719}{265381},\;\; \frac{4272943}{1360120},\;\; 
\frac{411557987}{131002976},\;\; \frac{2646693125139304345}{842468587426513207},
$$
$$
\frac{7809723338470423412693394150101387872685594299}{2485912146995414187767820081837036927319426665}.
$$

Comment: I love how Mathematica has a function for everything ... even convergents.

Comment: So the reason for the many primes is that primes and composite numbers were confused?

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes.  91 primes out of 100 is fairly surprising, but 91 composite numbers out of 100 is about what you would expect.